# Can XSD Assertions be Used in Specifying a WSDL File

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, xsd, wsdl

I have a WSDL file which also contains all types used in it (via `<wsdl:types>`
 tag). When defining the types, I have something like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="service"
        targetNamespace="http://www.xxx.yyy/reg/definitions" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:tax="http://www.xxx.yyy/reg/definitions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    .............
    <xs:complexType name="CompanyName">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="ShortName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Language" type="tax:LanguageType" use="required"/>
        <xs:assert test="ShortName or @Language != 'Language1'"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    .............
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work giving the following exception when I try to start the application on Tomcat:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'CompanyName' is invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

The WSDL version is 1.2 and I don't know which version of xsd it uses when types are described in it, so I don't know if it is a xsd version (1.0 vs. 1.1) issue or something else.

Can someone help me in finding the real issue?

**EDIT:** I have added the header of the wsdl.
 I have added the version attribute (`version="1.1"`) to `<xs:schema>`
definition but that didn't help either:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.xxx.yyy/reg/definitions" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.1">
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's a "real good answer" for this question, since in the text of the WSDL the reference to XSD is quite vague regarding supported versions (in https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20/#eii-types), and it is also specified (in §3.2) that other schema languages could be supported. The referenced recommendation for XML Schema is 1.0, however (in [§10.2 Normative references](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20/#Normative-References)).

Comment: @potame: It is really hard to find out the answer, but anyway, thank you for the support and for the links.

Comment: This is hard to debug without the `<xmlns:xs="...">` tag. Can you include the header of the WSDL?

Comment: @saarp: Please take a look at EDIT part of the question (I have added the required parts).

Comment: @Armine The schema above validates correctly when I add a space between the `xmlns:soap` and `xmlns:wsdl` namespace references in the `<wsdl:definitions>` tag. You could also try the updated wsdl schema URL of http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl.

Comment: @saarp: Sorry, the missing space is just a typo made during the copy paste and formatting in StackOverflow... I just corrected it. But it's really strange that it was possible to validate it. On my side, the start of the Tomcat complains on it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [assertions were introduced with XML Schema v1.1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/index.html) when the [XMLSchema definition moved over to w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/sawsdl/#Namespace).

Sample header:

```
<wsdl:description
  targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/sawsdl/spec/wsdl/order#"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/sawsdl/spec/wsdl/order#"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:sawsdl="http://www.w3.org/ns/sawsdl">
```

Comment: Yes, assertions have been introduced witt XSD v.1.1 so if I have an XSD of version 1.0 I cannot use assertions. But my question is about if I can use XSD v.1.1 with WSDL or no? I have added the version attribute (version="1.1") to <xs:schema> definition but that didn't help either.